# "onto the shelf" vs. "on the shelf"?

Tags: prepositions, articles, slang

When I write with a native speaker, she used the phrase "onto the shelf". Are they any differences between these two sentences?
I feel like "onto" is a slang or something... Please explain me this issue.

> I put something **onto the** shelf.

or

> I put something **on the** shelf.

Answer (score 4):

In the given examples, it would be difficult to decide which word goes there.

We generally use 'onto' when we talk about the direction to move because it contains 'to'. Say,

> The jockey jumped *onto* the horse.

We are talking about the jockey who is moving toward the horse to sit on it.

On the other hand, when there is no *movement,* we generally see 'on'.

> The book is *on* the table.

In your example, you are *putting* something. Now, the 'put' verb itself talks about the movement so I feel both are correct.

Let's wait for native speakers' input.

Comment: Both can work, depending on the sentence. Compare: she put it *into/in* the cupboard. But *shoved ... into* and *stored ... in* sound like better pairs.